# Loop through XML::Simple structure

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-simple

So I have some xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root result="0" >
    <settings user="anonymous" >
            <s n="blabla1" >
                    <v>true</v>
            </s>
            <s n="blabla2" >
                    <v>false</v>
            </s>
            <s n="blabla3" >
                    <v>true</v>
            </s>
    </settings>
</root>
```

I want to go through all the settings using the XML Simple.

Here's what I have when I print the output with Data::Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'settings' => {
                      'user' => 'anonymous',
                      's' => [
                               {
                                 'n' => 'blabla1',
                                 'v' => 'true'
                               },
                               {
                                 'n' => 'blabla2',
                                 'v' => 'false'
                               },
                               {
                                 'n' => 'blabla3',
                                 'v' => 'true'
                               }
                             ]
                    },
      'result' => '0'
    };
```

And here's my code

```
 $xml = new XML::Simple;
 $data = $xml->XMLin($file);
 foreach $s (keys %{ $data->{'settings'}->{'s'} }) {
  print "TEST: $s $data->{'settings'}->{'s'}->[$s]->{'n'} $data->{'settings'}->{'s'}->[$s]->{'v'}<br>\n";
 }
```

And it returns these 2 lines, without looping:

```
TEST: n blabla1 true
TEST: v blabla1 true
```

I also tried to do something like this:

```
foreach $s (keys @{ $data->{'settings'}->{'s'} }) {
```

Without any success:

```
Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not array dereference)
```

I can print:

```
$data->{'settings'}->{'s'}->[1]->{'n'} $data->{'settings'}->{'s'}->[1]->{'v'}
```

For each setting, but I can't loop through them.

How can I procede? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the square brackets in the dump: there is an array involved.

```
for (@{ $data->{settings}{s} }) {
    print $_->{n}, ' ', $_->{v}, "\n";
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode the `n` and `v`, just run `keys` on the dereferenced hash reference:

```
for my $s (@{ $data->{settings}{s} }) {
    print join(', ', map "$_ = $s->{$_}", keys %$s), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah damn, I left the word "keys" when I tried to parse the @array.

Comment: Assume you didn't know the names for they keys "n" and "v",  would you print out both the keys "n" and "v", along with their respective values?

Comment: @swl1020: Are you asking how to run `keys` on a hash reference?

Comment: I'm a very new Perl programmer, so I'm not sure what I'm asking. What I'm trying to do is modify this guy's loop so that instead of printing the values of N and V, it prints something like N=valuen V=valuev, but without hard coding the "N" and "V"